# Cross-entropy loss when some categories are broader than others

Tags: classification, loss-functions, cross-entropy

Let's say I want to write a classifier for pictures of dogs. Most importantly, I want to know whether something is a picture of a dog or not. Secondarily, it'd be nice to know what breed the dog is. In addition to providing a more useful model, I have an intuitive sense that the additional knowledge of the breed might help the dog/no-dog detection, as suggested by the WaveNet paper.

So I can generate a model to output a probability distribution over some categories:

- Collie
- Greyhound
- Chihuahua
- Dachshund
- ...
- Not a dog

I could just use cross-entropy to evaluate my model. However, the dog/no-dog distinction is way more important to me than getting the breed right. How can I design a loss function that models this?